# Problem with Proguard and consumer proguard in Android SDK 29

Tags: android, android-studio, proguard, aar

I have searched stackoverflow and proguard related questions and am still stuck.

I created an android .aar library (snifferservice) that holds hardware-related functions and a utility package. I use this for most of my Android apps that connect to this hardware device. I have also an application that only uses the utility package in the library.
I'm using Proguard to obfuscate and shrink my main app, NoseBook, and also using it to obfuscate and shrink the aar in the finished application. Since migrating to androidx and changing to target API 29 I can't create a release version because I get an error stating it can't find a common superclass for files which I specifically marked as `dontwarn`.

I tried playing with the proguard rules - adding and removing the other packages in the aar, and specifically the packages referenced in the error. Nothing works. If I don't apply Proguard to the aar at all everything compiles OK.

My app uses Firebase Uuthentication and Firebase Cloud Functions. I am using Android Studio 3.6.3 on Windows 10. Any ideas would be most appreciated.

The error:

```
Optimizing (pass 2/5)...
Unexpected error while performing partial evaluation:
  Class       = [weizmann/com/snifferservice/data/SaveDataService]
  Method      = [onCreate()V]
  Exception   = [java.lang.IllegalArgumentException] (Can't find common super class of [android/content/Context] (with 2 known super classes) and [weizmann/com/snifferservice/roomdata/SnifferDatabase] (with 1 known super classes))
Unexpected error while performing partial evaluation:
  Class       = [weizmann/com/snifferservice/services/BluetoothLeService]
  Method      = [onCreate()V]
  Exception   = [java.lang.IllegalArgumentException] (Can't find common super class of [android/content/Context] (with 2 known super classes) and [weizmann/com/snifferservice/roomdata/SnifferDatabase] (with 1 known super classes))
Unexpected error while performing partial evaluation:
  Class       = [weizmann/com/snifferservice/services/CloudDataService]
  Method      = [onHandleIntent(Landroid/content/Intent;)V]
  Exception   = [java.lang.IllegalArgumentException] (Can't find common super class of [android/content/Context] (with 2 known super classes) and [weizmann/com/snifferservice/roomdata/SnifferDatabase] (with 1 known super classes))
Warning: Exception while processing task java.io.IOException: java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Can't find common super class of [android/content/Context] (with 2 known super classes) and [weizmann/com/snifferservice/roomdata/SnifferDatabase] (with 1 known super classes)
Thread(Tasks limiter_4): destruction
```

My app build.gradle: compilesdk and targetsdk are 29.

```
release {
            minifyEnabled true
            shrinkResources true
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
            consumerProguardFiles 'consumer-proguard-rules.pro' //If I comment out this line everything works
        }
...
dependencies {
implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.0.0'
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:1.1.3'
    implementation 'androidx.recyclerview:recyclerview:1.0.0'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.1'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.1.0'

    implementation project(':SnifferService-7.142')

    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:17.0.0'
    implementation 'com.firebaseui:firebase-ui-auth:4.3.1'

    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:16.0.9'

    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-functions:17.0.0'
}
```

My top level build.gradle:

```
 dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.2.0'
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.1.0'
    }
```

aar build.gradle: compilesdk and targetsdk are 28

```
dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    implementation 'androidx.recyclerview:recyclerview:1.0.0'
    androidTestImplementation('androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.1.0', {
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
    })
    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.0.0'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    implementation 'com.github.PhilJay:MPAndroidChart:v3.0.1'
    //gson
    implementation 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.8.0'
    //volley
    implementation 'com.android.volley:volley:1.1.1'
    
    implementation 'net.mabboud:android-tone-player:0.3'

    def room_version = "2.2.5"
    implementation "androidx.room:room-runtime:$room_version"
    annotationProcessor "androidx.room:room-compiler:$room_version" // For Kotlin use kapt instead of annotationProcessor
    // Test helpers
    testImplementation "androidx.room:room-testing:$room_version"

    // Core library
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test:core:1.0.0'

    // AndroidJUnitRunner and JUnit Rules
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test:runner:1.1.0'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test:rules:1.1.0'

    // Assertions
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.0.0'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:truth:1.0.0'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.google.truth:truth:0.42'

}
```

top level Proguard rules:

```
-android
-dontpreverify
-repackageclasses ''
-allowaccessmodification
-optimizations !code/simplification/arithmetic
-keepattributes *Annotation*

# chart
-dontwarn com.github.mikephil.**

#continuous buzzer
-dontwarn net.mabboud.android_tone_player.**

# gson
-dontwarn com.google.gson.**

# android support
-keep class android.support.v4.app.** { *; }
-keep class android.support.v7.app.** { *; }

-keep interface android.support.v4.app.** { *; }

#androidx
-dontwarn com.google.android.material.**
-keep class com.google.android.material.** { *; }

-dontwarn androidx.**
-keep class androidx.** { *; }
-keep interface androidx.** { *; }

# monocontinuous buzzer
-dontwarn weizmann.com.snifferservice.audio.MonoContinuousBuzzer

#gmailsender
-dontwarn java.awt.**
-dontwarn java.beans.Beans
-dontwarn javax.security.**

# don't need device-related stuff
-dontwarn weizmann.com.snifferservice.communication.*
-dontwarn weizmann.com.snifferservice.fragments.*
-dontwarn weizmann.com.snifferservice.supportfragments.*
-dontwarn weizmann.com.snifferservice.services.*
-dontwarn weizmann.com.snifferservice.roomdata.*
-dontwarn weizmann.com.snifferservice.data.*


# This will strip `Log.v`, `Log.d`, and `Log.i` statements and will leave `Log.w` and `Log.e` statements intact.
-assumenosideeffects class android.util.Log {
    public static boolean isLoggable(java.lang.String, int);
    public static int v(...);
    public static int d(...);
    public static int i(...);
}


-keep public class * extends android.app.Activity
-keep public class * extends android.app.Application
```

consumer-proguard-rules.pro:

```
-dontwarn weizmann.com.snifferservice.communication.*
-dontwarn weizmann.com.snifferservice.fragments.*
-dontwarn weizmann.com.snifferservice.supportfragments.*
-dontwarn weizmann.com.snifferservice.services.*
-dontwarn weizmann.com.snifferservice.roomdata.*
-dontwarn weizmann.com.snifferservice.data.*
-keep class weizmann.com.snifferservice.util.** {*;}
```

I have tried adding to this file also the `support.v4` and `support.v7` commands and also adding and removing `android.content.*` and `weizmann.com.snifferservice.data.*` and `weizmann.com.snifferservice.roomdata.*` , doesn't help.

**EDIT**
The problem seems to be with the Room Database. These are the Proguard errors:

```
Warning: weizmann.com.snifferservice.roomdata.SnifferDatabase_Impl: can't find referenced field 'java.util.List mCallbacks' in program class weizmann.com.snifferservice.roomdata.SnifferDatabase_Impl
Warning: weizmann.com.snifferservice.roomdata.SnifferDatabase_Impl: can't find referenced method 'void internalInitInvalidationTracker(androidx.sqlite.db.SupportSQLiteDatabase)' in program class weizmann.com.snifferservice.roomdata.SnifferDatabase_Impl
Warning: weizmann.com.snifferservice.roomdata.SnifferDatabase_Impl: can't find referenced field 'androidx.sqlite.db.SupportSQLiteDatabase mDatabase' in program class weizmann.com.snifferservice.roomdata.SnifferDatabase_Impl
Warning: weizmann.com.snifferservice.roomdata.SnifferDatabase_Impl: can't find referenced method 'void assertNotMainThread()' in program class weizmann.com.snifferservice.roomdata.SnifferDatabase
Warning: weizmann.com.snifferservice.roomdata.SnifferDatabase_Impl: can't find referenced method 'androidx.sqlite.db.SupportSQLiteOpenHelper getOpenHelper()' in program class weizmann.com.snifferservice.roomdata.SnifferDatabase
Warning: weizmann.com.snifferservice.roomdata.SnifferDatabase_Impl: can't find referenced method 'void beginTransaction()' in program class weizmann.com.snifferservice.roomdata.SnifferDatabase
Warning: weizmann.com.snifferservice.roomdata.SnifferDatabase_Impl: can't find referenced method 'void setTransactionSuccessful()' in program class weizmann.com.snifferservice.roomdata.SnifferDatabase
Warning: weizmann.com.snifferservice.roomdata.SnifferDatabase_Impl: can't find referenced method 'void endTransaction()' in program class weizmann.com.snifferservice.roomdata.SnifferDatabase
```

I have added to my proguard variations on the following, nothing helps.

```
#this
-dontwarn android.arch.util.paging.CountedDataSource
-dontwarn android.arch.persistence.room.paging.LimitOffsetDataSource

#or this
-keep class androidx.room.**{
    public protected private *;
}
#or this
-keep class * extends androidx.room.RoomDatabase
#or this
-keep class androidx.room.RoomDatabase
#or this and various combinations.
-dontwarn androidx.room.paging.**
```

Comment: Show us the androidx/support dependencies of both your app and library. Also, what min/max/target sdk do the library and the app have?

Comment: Why exactly are you using `dontwarn` anyways? I mean the error you're getting would have had a warning/error while compiling the library (but it didn't since you added `dontwarn`). Looking at the ProGuard manual, it seems you really need a good reason to use that flag. If you get an error without `dontwarn` I suggest you rather fix that.

Comment: @JensV, thanks for answering. I added the dependencies as requested. minsdk is 21, target of aar is 28 and target of top level app is 29. I have other apps which I migrated to androidx and sdk 29 without issues, but they also use the device libraries and not only the utility functions.

Comment: @JensV, I understood that ```dontwarn``` is for parts of the code I'm not using and don't care if have problems. This isn't correct? If it is correct, why is the build failing on classes I'm not using? If not, what do you recommend I put instead? Thank you.

Comment: Did some more digging.. you should not use `-repackageclasses ''` on android... Try reducing your issue to a subset of code by continually removing stuff. Also try clearing caches and perform a clean build

Comment: This is also a good read https://www.guardsquare.com/en/products/proguard/manual/usage

Comment: Could you replace all `-dontwarn` with `-ignorewarnings` and give the output with all the warnings?

Comment: @JensV, I put ```-ignorewarnings``` on top and removed the ```-dontwarn``` commands. I updated the question to ignore one line out of every package, otherwise it was too long. Still working on reducing the issue. Thanks

Comment: @JensV, The problem seems to be in Room Database. I updated the question to show the errors.

Comment: https://www.guardsquare.com/en/products/proguard/manual/troubleshooting this suggests your build is an inconsistent state. Try cleaning your build cache and perhaps attempt to clear other caches as well (gradlew clean, invalidate caches, etc.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What finally worked: The error always appeared on the 2nd optimization pass. I added

```
-optimizationpasses 1
```

to the options at the beginning and the error never appeared.

I tried various clear cache options, updating/reverting the version of the internal aar, adding removing numerous proguard options, with no success. Worst case also gave a STRING_TOO_LARGE error.

Thanks JensV for your help!

Any further ideas to solve this problem would still be appreciated.